# How do I stream/send javascript array elements to a S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, amazon-s3

I am working on reducing the memory needs of a data gatherer, where a small percentage of the requests can result in ram usage of > 5gb. The final output is a stringified JSON object with a very long array, up to 500,000 objects.

The data gatherer gets 500 records at a time, in the format of an array of json objects. Currently, the array is concatenated onto an accumulator variable. When there is a massive record request, 200,000+, the variable starts taking up a large amount of memory, requiring that our EC2 instances have 10gb of ram.

I'm looking for a way to take each set of records and appends them to a S3 file to optimize ram utilization. Mocking the effect of streaming each record set changed the ram usage in one example from 2gb down to 30mb.

After the file is stored in S3, it is downloaded by another program and converted into different formats based upon user settings.

I've looked into Firehose as well as multi-part upload, but I don't see an exact solution based on how it is currently structured. I am able to change how the saved file is formatted, but limited to it being located in S3. Current format is:

```
{
  count: 5555,
  results: [
    {record1},
    {record2},
    ...
    {record200000}
  ]
}
```

I would like to keep the existing file format as close to its current form as possible, but a complete change is able to be done, would just require additional work on the reading programs side.

Comment: Does it need to be sent/processed in realtime? Could you just write the JSON data to a local file, then upload the file once all the records are processed?

Comment: Have you tried using Minio Client? You can send a stream directly into s3 with this [method](https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference#putObject)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It does not have to be real-time processed. There is a several hour gap between file generation and a user interaction in most cases. Using local storage was something I had considered, but the main goal was to lower maximum possible ram usage. And I may be mistaken, but doesn't writing to file take the total amount of ram of the json objects size? It was my thought that streaming it as it was coming in would have been easier than it seems to be.

Comment: Why do you wish to keep data in RAM? Can't it just take one input record, process it, then append it to a local file? It's like "streaming to a local file".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein This processing happens in an ec2 docker instance, and I'm trying to minimize RAM usage, as right now there needs to be 10gb allocated. Having 'local storage' added to the container is an option. The main goal is to reduce the RAM, how I go about it is my choice. After processing, the file is read from S3 by another program. So as long as it ends up in S3, preferably in the same format as it's currently being saved, it's all good.